# RPM SPEC file not actually doing anything, just installing?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

This is my first foray into Linux RPM creation, and I am exploring it as a solution to distribute a package of software that consists mostly of files and some configuration.

I have read through some documentation, but I feel some sections are ambiguous between the build system, and the target installation system.

I have written a SPEC file for rpmbuild, and it builds the RPM, but it seems to not do anything when I install it on the local system. It just says it was installed.

I have removed almost all aspects, and am just trying to get RPM to create a directory. It is not being created.

Anything wrong I am doing here?

```
%define _topdir     /sourcecode/agent/rpm/
%define name        agent
%define release     0
%define version     0.1a
%define buildroot %{_topdir}/BUILD

BuildRoot:      %{buildroot}
Summary:        agent
License:        GNU
Name:           %{name}
Version:        %{version}
Release:        %{release}
Source0:        hello.sh
Prefix:         /opt
Group:          PhysicalEdge

%prep

%build

%install
mkdir -p /opt/edgeagent
cp %{SOURCE0} /opt/edgeagent/hello.sh

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
```

Another question I had was to include files, I have listed them in Source's (Source0: hello.sh). Do I list them in the %files directive where they started on the source system, or where they end up on the target system?

I am trying to get the file hello.sh into /opt/agent/ on the target system for now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:
`cp %{SOURCE0} /opt/edgeagent/hello.sh`

You shouldn't **ever** build RPMs as root! This command **should have failed**.

What you wanted is:

```
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/opt/edgeagent/
cp %{SOURCE0} %{buildroot}/opt/edgeagent/hello.sh
```

Then add `/opt/edgeagent/hello.sh` to the `%files` section as you speculated.

Comment: I would just more of explanation - in %install you are addressing files on the build systems (your machine). In %files section you are referring to file path on the target system.